# How to select specific elements in a list and use them (Python)

Tags: python, list

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can I pick one element and use it in a calculation?

For example, to pick just the second element on its own. Would it then be possible to store it in another list?

Thanks

Comment: That is one of the first steps of Python. It's fine to ask but if you want to ask such basic questions, you end up asking numerous quotations which would be a very slow process. I would recommend reading some good book or taking a course. It won't cost you more than a few days to become reasonably good in Python.

Answer (score 1):

You can access and item by its index.

```
list = ["A","B","C"]
list[0]  # returns A
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
>>> l=[]
>>> numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l.append(numbers[1])
>>> l
[2]
>>>
```

Use `append` and indexing.

And then, `l` will have a value which is the second element of `numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5]
# Picking up '2' from the list
no = numbers[1] # Since list index starts at 0
print(no)  # Prints 2
```

For storing in another list, you need to declare an empty list where you'll store the value. Like below:

```
l = []
l.append(no)  # Now l contains 2
print(l)  # Prints [2]
```